# How to remove trailing zeros in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting, digits

I have a R data.frame that looks like this:

```
   Gene    Score
1  AAT2 15.40100
2  ACB1  5.11880
3  ACF2 15.04500
4 ADE16  3.04080
5 ADE17  0.28143
6  ADE4 19.79200
```

However I need to get rid of the trailing zeros in order to get:

```
   Gene    Score
1  AAT2 15.401
2  ACB1  5.1188
3  ACF2 15.045
4 ADE16  3.0408
5 ADE17  0.28143
6  ADE4 19.792
```

Basically I am trying to set the number of digits in the score column to 5 digits; I specifically want the data to be viewed in that way. How can I do this in R?

Comment: What is the _type_ of the `Score` column?  If numeric, then what you are currently seeing is just how R is presenting the data.  The trailing zeroes are not _significant_, and are also not really being stored.  On the other hand, if you want to _view_ your numeric data this, it is another story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to *view* your `Score` data as text, with no trailing zeroes, then use:

```
df_view <- df[c("Gene", "Score")]
df_view$Score <- sub("0+$", "", as.character(df_view$Score))

df_view

   Gene   Score
1  AAT2  15.401
2  ACB1  5.1188
3  ACF2  15.045
4 ADE16  3.0408
5 ADE17 0.28143
6  ADE4  19.792
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Gene=c("AAT2", "ACB1", "ACF2", "ADE16", "ADE17", "ADE4"),
                 Score=c(15.40100, 5.11880, 15.04500, 3.04080, 0.28143, 19.79200),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

We could just use `as.character` and it will remove the trailing 0s

```
df_view$Score <- as.character(df$Score)
df_view$Score
#[1] "15.401"  "5.1188"  "15.045"  "3.0408"  "0.28143" "19.792"
```

#### data

```
df_view <- data.frame(Gene=c("AAT2", "ACB1", "ACF2", "ADE16", "ADE17", "ADE4"),
                 Score=c(15.40100, 5.11880, 15.04500, 3.04080, 0.28143, 19.79200),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```