# How to round/format a vector of numbers dynamically without using a loop?

Tags: r

I have two vectors of numbers: `v1` and `v2`  The first is a set of real numbers. The second is a set of decimal places that I want to round or format `v1`.

Here are the vectors:

```
v1 <- c(7.449835, 6.649058, 9.072736, 5.643506, 8.979166, 5.544238, 1.746717, 4.151327, 8.408533, 1.176206)
v2 <- c(1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3)
```

The result I want is this:

```
[1] 7.4 6.64 9 5.643 8.9791 5.544238 1.7 4.15 8.40 1.176
```

...where the first vector is rounded/formatted according to the second vector. I don't care if the result is a character or number vector. But in the end, there are a lot of numbers and I don't want to use a loop:

Notice that this doesn't work:

```
format(v1, digits = v2)
 [1] "7" "7" "9" "6" "9" "6" "2" "4" "8" "1"
```

And this doesn't work:

```
round(v1, digits = v2)
[1] 7.400000 6.650000 9.000000 5.644000 8.979200 5.544238 1.700000 4.150000 8.410000 1.176000
```

So, how can I dynamically round or format a vector without using a loop in R?

Comment: I just mocked up the desired result by deleting digits.  Rounding is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?sprintf` `fmt` argument can take "*a character vector of format strings*".

So you can piece the formats together by pasting the format digits vector with the `sprintf` format syntax e.g. `paste0("%#.", v2, "f")`.

All together

```
sprintf(v1, fmt=paste0("%#.", v2, "f"))
```

Comment: The "9." is bugging me but I can figure that out.  Thanks.

Comment: this seems to do it `sprintf(v1, fmt=paste0("%.", v2, "f"))` . Updated answer

Comment: actually rolling back as it doesn't  treat intgers as expected , see `sprintf(1, fmt=paste0("%.", 1, "f"))`. I'm sure there will be a way!!#

Comment: Yes, it ends up as "1.0000".  Let's leave your comment above though, as it might be useful in the right situation.  If you always start with a floating point number.

Comment: actually I think the comment may be okay.... Im confusing myself . I meant to do `sprintf(1, fmt=paste0("%.", 0, "f"))` which works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `round`, then remove the trailing zeros as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212813/how-to-remove-trailing-zeros-in-r-dataframe)

```
v1 <- c(7.449835, 6.649058, 9.072736, 5.643506, 8.979166, 5.544238, 1.746717, 4.151327, 8.408533, 1.176206)
v2 <- c(1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3)
v1 <- round(v1, digits = v2)
v1 <- sub("0+$", "", as.character(v1))
```

Comment: I actually didn't notice that round() was working except for the extra zeros.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you round first and then apply as.character you get the desired output:

```
mapply(function(x,y){as.character(round(x,y))}, v1, v2)
#[1] "7.4"      "6.65"     "9"        "5.644"    "8.9792"   "5.544238" "1.7"      "4.15"     "8.41"     "1.176"   

# to get without quotes use `cat` or `print( ... , quote=FALSE)`
cat( mapply(function(x,y){as.character(round(x,y))}, v1, v2))
#7.4 6.65 9 5.644 8.9792 5.544238 1.7 4.15 8.41 1.176
```